# Where can I set the default folder view?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to hardwire Windows Explorer to use the Details view as a default?](https://superuser.com/questions/133196/is-there-a-way-to-hardwire-windows-explorer-to-use-the-details-view-as-a-default)

I want to set all my files and folders in Windows to show as *Extra large icons*.

It seems that Windows is saving this apart for each folder...

Where can I tell my system to use the view type everywhere?

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to hardwire Windows Explorer to use the Details view as a default?](http://superuser.com/questions/133196/is-there-a-way-to-hardwire-windows-explorer-to-use-the-details-view-as-a-default)

Comment: @techie007: Interesting, didn't show up in the suggested duplicates nor in the relevant questions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Go to a folder setup how you want it.
- Hit "Alt" to show the Menu.
- Pick Tools-->Folder Options.
- Pick the View tab.
- Click "Apply To All Folders".

This may not work so well for library folders, as Windows 7 likes to treat them special. :)

Comment: I just have to do the same action for each Library, will accept your answer (in 7 min) until I see deviation.