# How to set the default View mode of File Explorer to "Tiles"?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to hardwire Windows Explorer to use the Details view as a default?](https://superuser.com/questions/133196/is-there-a-way-to-hardwire-windows-explorer-to-use-the-details-view-as-a-default)

In File Explorer, the first time a folder is opened the files are listed in **Details** View.

(Although I think if a folder has video files only, the files are listed in **Large icons** view in Windows 8).

[image]

I ultimately set the View do **Tiles** since I find larger icons easier on the eye. And I find it extremely annoying to have to change it manually every time I open a new Folder.

Does anyone know if it is possible to make the File Explorer open all files in **Tiles** View (or any other View for that matter).

[image]

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to hardwire Windows Explorer to use the Details view as a default?](http://superuser.com/questions/133196/is-there-a-way-to-hardwire-windows-explorer-to-use-the-details-view-as-a-default) and/or [Where can I set the default folder view?](http://superuser.com/questions/410074/where-can-i-set-the-default-folder-view?)