# Windows 10 version 1803 - strange behaviour when opening folders containing TypeScript files

Tags: windows-explorer, icons, windows-10-v1803

Windows never stop surprising me with its strange behaviours.

This time, after I updated to v. 1803 (build 17134.706) I have this annoying thing when opening folders <strike>containing TypeScript files</strike> of Ionic projects, explorer takes a bit to load the list (even if it is very small) and when done it displays the files as `Large Icons` instead of `Details`

[image]

Has anybody else experienced this issue?

**Update 1**

I did what I found in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/133200/479682) and something changed

[image]

at least the list remains as `Details` but the slow loading is still there

**Update 2**

It seems this is not related to TypeScript files but happens in folders inside a Ionic project folder.

**Update 3**

As @Biswapriyo suggested in [a comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1426513/windows-10-version-1803-strange-behaviour-when-opening-folders-containing-type#comment2152556_1426513) I tried to uninstall Sublime Text and nothing has changed, I also tried running in Safe Mode as suggested by @Ramhound in [another comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1426513/windows-10-version-1803-strange-behaviour-when-opening-folders-containing-type#comment2152608_1426513) and the issue is still there

Comment: I get a similar behavior when I right-click and go to New >....it takes forever to load and icons flash...not sure if related.

Comment: @Peter does this happen after the 1803 update?

Comment: Try this: 1. Uninstall the sublime text editor 2. Delete icon cache (google it) 3. Reboot 4. Reinstall Sublime text editor (or try other to check any difference).

Comment: @Biswapriyo I will try as soon as I can (I am working now) but much probably it is not related to Sublime Text because it happened even before of associating it to `.ts` files and on folders outside of Ionic where there are other files I open wit Sublime Text (`.css`, `.js`, `.xml` and so on..) everything is ok

Comment: Incidentally, `.ts` could also be a (MPEG) Transport Stream, an audio/video container. May or may not be related to the problem you’re seeing.

Comment: @DanielB it may a lot, windows suggested opening my `.ts` files with `Films & TV` app before I changed it to `Sublime Text` but I tried creating a `.ts` file on different and random folders where everything shows fast and with no problems

Comment: Does this behavior exhibit itself while in Safe Mode?  Instead of submitting a comment edit your question so the required vital information is included.